# Why does args.input shows me none type error

Tags: python

I get a error like this when run it in my terminal

```
filename = open(input(), 'rb') 
input_file = filename
open(args.input_file, "rb").read()
```

This is output

````
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType```





This is also there in script 

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser();
parser.add_argument("-i", dest="input_file", help="no file with this name") 
args = parser.parse_args();```

The path i put is /storage/emulated/0/filrname.txt
````

Comment: what is the value of `input`?

Comment: Open expects a string. You gave it nothing.

Comment: I gave the input after the edit you can see it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filename = open(input(), 'rb')
```

This will open the filename that you entered in the terminal and return a `file` object, the `filename` object is not the name of the file.

```
open(args.input_file, "rb").read()
```

`args` is not defined in the script you provided. Even if it was, `args.input` is probably not set. That might cause the `TypeError`.

I assume you're trying to open the file entered by the user, you can do it like this:

```
filename = input()
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
```